# how to set rates_mode to none in rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq

This is bugging me for a while, in rabbitMQ I keep getting:

> The management statistics database currently has a queue of [some number] events to process. If this number keeps increasing, so will the memory used by the management plugin. You may find it useful to set the rates_mode config item to none.

My applications requires the management part to get the current queue names. so I can't just stop it.

but how can I do it without breaking the current queues in rabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0):

`rates_mode` is about how the queues report statistics. So if you want to disable that, then just do it: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

You will still be able to list/inspect queues on the management plugin